# When tap on button how to go to collectionview in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

Like amazon and any other apps when we click on top review stars we are going to all reviews like that I need when i click on my app review stars(which is in the top) i need to scroll upto my all reviews collectionview in the same screen

**code:** when i tried like this i am scrolling to full bottom of the screen but i need up to my collectionview position. how to go till collectionview. please guide me

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var reviewCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func reviewStarsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height), animated: true)
}
```

o/p: if i click here i need to goto collectionview

[image]

**EDIT:** this is my design hierarchy in storyboard

[image]

**code:** `reviewCollectionView` code

```
let layout3 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()


override func viewDidLoad() {

    layout3.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout3.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout3.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout3.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout3.itemSize = CGSize(width: reviewCollectionView.bounds.width, height: reviewCollectionView.bounds.height)
    reviewCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout3
    reviewCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    reviewCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    layout3.itemSize = CGSize(width: reviewCollectionView.bounds.width, height: reviewCollectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

with @son answer

[image][image]

Comment: can you please let us know what is the constant you are getting `reviewCollectionView.frame.origin.y` from here in layout subview.

Comment: @Jatin i got value in both layoutsubview and inside reviewstarsTapped button is `45.5`

Comment: so that's wrong right? i seen @son update his code it might work if it's not let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you added collectionView directly as scrollView's subview. Firstly, you have to get the collection view frame (according to its super view, in this case, is scrollView). Then `setContentOffset` of the scrollView to this position. That's it.

```swift
...
@IBAction func reviewStarsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let collectionViewYPosition = reviewCollectionView.convert(reviewCollectionView.frame.origin, to: self.view).y
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: collectionViewYPosition), animated: true)
}
```

Edited: Because the collectionView is nested so many layers, so you have to convert it's frame according to scrollView.

Comment: i have added my storyboard design hierarchy in my post. please once check

Comment: with your code if i tap on reviewStarsTapped then it just scrolls half inch or 1 inch.. i need to scroll upto collectionview.. where am i wrong

Comment: i have added `reviewCollectionView` code as well in my post

Comment: @swiftdoubts yeah, cause its nested so many. I edited the answer, take a look.

Comment: it should show only upto white colour BG.. but below white Background got so much other space why?

Comment: if i give like this `let collectionViewYPosition = reviewCollectionView.convert(reviewCollectionView.frame.origin, to: self.view).y
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: collectionViewYPosition - 170), animated: true)` got so much space below white BG why? any idea?

Comment: note: here reviews collectionview is at the bottom of the screen

Comment: will accept your answer.. if you know the answer please let me know the reason

Comment: @swiftdoubts I think the contentSize of scrollView does not enough for collectionView to scroll to the top of view in this scenario. However, I'm not sure. The trick is adding a view as extra spacing at the bottom and letting auto layout do its job.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer given by [@son](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214202/son) is correct, but if it is not working then try with `bounds` instead of `frame`.

```
@IBAction func reviewStarsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let position = reviewCollectionView.convert(reviewCollectionView.bounds.origin, to: self. scrollView)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: position), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: when i use this code nothing happens.. i have added storyboard design hierarchy in post please once gothrough it